# How post to wall facebook android-sdk:4.0.0

Tags: java, android, facebook

Please help

I hava code for button post to wall :

```
btnPostToWall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        postToWall();
    }
});

public void postToWall() {
    // post on user's wall.
    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });

}
```

But I Have New Faceboof android sdk 4.0.0 and this code depreacated

How post to wall whith new library?

I read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android), but I don't understand how to use

Comment: If you want to just post text, you have to use me/feed and build your own method: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph, for the rest sharing options, the docs you pointed out have clear examples. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it's not quite the solution you are looking for, but I'm using it.

Facebook Android SDK 4 has class `ShareApi` for sharing your content. This class has static method `share()`:

```
public static void share(
            final ShareContent shareContent,
            final FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> callback) {
        new ShareApi(shareContent)
                .share(callback);
    }
```

and non static private String `message`. So when you're trying to share something (for ex.

```
ShareApi api = new ShareApi(content);
api.setMessage("My message");
api.share(content, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() ...)
```

) will be created new instance of `ShareApi` with `message = null` and your message won't be added.

**The solution:**

1. Open class `ShareApi` if you're using Facebook SDK as external library OR copy this class from Github https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/share/ShareApi.java
   if you're using Maven repository.
2. Change this code:

   ```
   public static void share(
       final ShareContent shareContent,
       final FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> callback) {
   new ShareApi(shareContent)
           .share(callback);
   }
   ```

   to this one:

   ```
   public static void share(final String message,
       final ShareContent shareContent,
       final FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> callback) {
   new ShareApi(message, shareContent)
           .share(callback);
   }
   ```
3. Change this code:

   ```
   public ShareApi(final ShareContent shareContent) {
       this.shareContent = shareContent;
       this.graphNode = DEFAULT_GRAPH_NODE;
   }
   ```

   to this one:

   ```
   public ShareApi(String message, final ShareContent shareContent) {
       this.message = message;
       this.shareContent = shareContent;
       this.graphNode = DEFAULT_GRAPH_NODE;
   }
   ```
4. Use your changed `ShareApi` class for sharing your content:

   ```
   ShareApi.share("My message", content, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {

           @Override
           public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
               if (AppConfig.DEBUG) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS");
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onCancel() {
               if (AppConfig.DEBUG) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "CANCELLED");
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onError(FacebookException error) {
               if (AppConfig.DEBUG) {
                   Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
               }
           }
       });
   ```

If you just want to share text, you can use code below for `content` object:

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .build();
```

You've already read this manual https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android and can add different `ShareContent` to your post. Use [examples from Facebook Github repository](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/HelloFacebookSample/src/com/facebook/samples/hellofacebook/HelloFacebookSampleActivity.java) for better understanding new SDK.

P.S. Of course, you should have valid access token and `publish_actions` permission.

Comment: Great answer, it helped me out, but I'd like to suggest a change. Instead of altering the ShareApi class, just call `api.share(new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() ...)` with ShareApi reference you just created. This non-static share function may have not been public when you wrote the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The official Facebook documentation on how to share from Android SDK 4.0 is located here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

That link has examples of how to share by calling the Graph API or sharing by calling the native Facebook app dialog.

Here is how I implemented the share dialog in my own app:

in the xml for the activity/fragment I added the `Button`

```
  <Button
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        android:id="@+id/shareFacebookButton"
        android:text=""
        android:background="@drawable/facebook_button"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        />
```

Then inside the Fragment:

```
Button shareButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.shareFacebookButton);
shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new 

FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {}

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {}

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {}
});

shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
             ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
                .setContentDescription("The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")

             .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
                            .build();

         shareDialog.show(linkContent);
          }
     }});
```

Now when someone clicks on the button they will be met with the Facebook dialog like you would expect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to post an image along with content title and description?

Comment: just use `.setImageUrl(imageUrl)` where `imageUrl` is a valid `URI` object type.

Answer (score 1):

This is full working (13.02.2017) example based on Max answer.

Gradle: compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

```
public class ShareOnFacebook extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "ShareOnFacebook";

    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        shareOnWall();
    }

    void shareOnWall() {
        ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new

                FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: ");
                        Toast.makeText(ShareOnFacebook.this, "onSuccess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onCancel: ");
                        Toast.makeText(ShareOnFacebook.this, "onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onError: ");
                        Toast.makeText(ShareOnFacebook.this, "onError" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
            ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
                    .setContentDescription("The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
                    .build();

            shareDialog.show(linkContent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


}
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android,
  

As of April 18, 2017, the following parameters are no longer supported by Graph API versions 2.9 and higher. For versions 2.8 and lower, the parameters will continue working until July 17, 2017.

a contentTitle that represents the title of the content in the link
a imageURL, the URL of thumbnail image that will appear on the post
a contentDescription of the content, usually 2-4 sentences.  

In short all need to check the facebook documentation everytime